# Nested SQL selection - identical select for deeper results

Tags: sql, select, recursive-query

I have only one table that has all the required data in it. The initial selection is like this:

```
  SELECT t_mitm as MainArt, t_sitm as secondaryArt, t_qana as quantity 
    FROM ttibom010201 
WHERE TRIM(t_mitm) = N'ACL-3382040385-4'
```

The returned result is:

```
  MainArt                        secondaryArt      Quantity

 ACL-3382040385-4            ACL-4812070395-4 M1    1
 ACL-3382040385-4            ACL-4812070395-4 M3    1
 ACL-3382040385-4            ACL-4812070395-4 M2    1
 ACL-3382040385-4            30201039               0,032
```

I want to check the `secondaryArt` if the result starts with '30%' for all columns and if it does not start with '30%' to perform the exact same query for it - these example should perform it 3 times for first 3 rows because
there are 3 elements that do not start with '30%' **( ACL-4812070395-4 M1 , ACL-4812070395-4 M3 , ACL-4812070395-4 M2)**.

Here is the example of first row. It must execute:

```
select t_mitm as MainArt, t_sitm as secondaryArt, t_qana as quantity 
from ttibom010201 
where TRIM(t_mitm) = N'ACL-4812070395-4 M1'
```

So here there is also chance to return for `secondaryArt` data starting with '30%' or something else. If it is something else must perform again these query for elements in it.

Basically, in the end all returned elements should have `secondaryArt` starting with '30%'

How can I make it automatic only in SQL? Is it possible or I should fetch data 1 by 1 from my JS code?

---

UPDATE:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyData` (
  `MainArt` char(200) NOT NULL,
  `secondaryArt` char(200) NOT NULL
)


INSERT INTO `MyData` (`MainArt`, `secondaryArt`) VALUES
  ('ACL-3382040385-4', 'ACL-4812070395-4 M1'),
  ('ACL-3382040385-4', 'ACL-4812070395-4 M3'),
  ('ACL-3382040385-4', 'ACL-4812070395-4 M2'),
  ('ACL-3382040385-4', '30201039'),
  ('ACL-4812070395-4 M1', '30102024'),
  ('ACL-4812070395-4 M3', '30102024'),
  ('ACL-4812070395-4 M2', '30170054')
```

If I have this data for creating table, I want to be able to get all data for **ACL-3382040385-4** until there are only `secondaryArt` starting with'30%'.

For example:
1st SELECT statement:

```
SELECT t_mitm as MainArt, t_sitm as secondaryArt, t_qana as quantity 
            FROM ttibom010201 
        WHERE TRIM(t_mitm) = N'ACL-3382040385-4'
```

So the result select is:

```
 MainArt                        secondaryArt     

 ACL-3382040385-4            ACL-4812070395-4 M1    
 ACL-3382040385-4            ACL-4812070395-4 M3    
 ACL-3382040385-4            ACL-4812070395-4 M2    
 ACL-3382040385-4            30201039
```

2nd SELECT statement must have all these  M1, M2, M3 selected so they will show as secondaryArt '30%'

```
SELECT t_mitm as MainArt, t_sitm as secondaryArt, t_qana as quantity 
    FROM ttibom010201 
WHERE TRIM(t_mitm) = N'ACL-4812070395-4 M1'


SELECT t_mitm as MainArt, t_sitm as secondaryArt, t_qana as quantity 
    FROM ttibom010201 
WHERE TRIM(t_mitm) = N'ACL-4812070395-4 M2'


SELECT t_mitm as MainArt, t_sitm as secondaryArt, t_qana as quantity 
    FROM ttibom010201 
WHERE TRIM(t_mitm) = N'ACL-4812070395-4 M3'
```

FINAL result must look like this:

```
     ACL-3382040385-4            30201039       (FROM FIRST SELECT )       
     ACL-4812070395-4 M1             30102024   (FROM SECOND/LOOP SELECT )  
     ACL-4812070395-4 M2             30170054   (FROM SECOND/LOOP SELECT )  
     ACL-4812070395-4 M3             30102024   (FROM SECOND/LOOP SELECT )
```

Comment: If you can run loop without running in sql then things will become 10x easier, maybe try to have something indicate where to run the loop: `case when secondaryArt like '30%' then 0 else 1 end as flag`

Comment: you still can try to loop in sql but I'll never do this if there is any other choice cause sql is not design for this at all.

Comment: @T.Peter It won't be faster at all. Because you are going to fetch again and again for every result different than '30%'

Comment: just realize that... maybe doing this with recursive CTE?

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. better you add some sample raw data and desired output in text format for more clarity. Otherwise your question may get closed.

Comment: @BorislavStefanov added answer. Let me know if it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a scenario of Recursive Query. In your example only 2 Level scenario is there but it will work for deeper levels as well.

If your **MySQL** Version is **8.0** then you can use `Recursive CTE`:

```
with recursive cte as(

SELECT MainArt, secondaryArt 
            FROM MyData 
        WHERE TRIM(MainArt) = N'ACL-3382040385-4'
union all
select 
MyData.MainArt, MyData.secondaryArt
from MyData inner join cte on cte.secondaryArt=MyData.mainArt
        )
select * from cte where secondaryArt  like '30%'
```

If your MySql version is  **5.X** then you can use variable method as below query:

```
select  MainArt,
        secondaryArt
from    (select * from MyData
         order by MainArt, secondaryArt) list_sorted,
        (select @pv := 'ACL-3382040385-4') initialisation
where   find_in_set(MainArt, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', secondaryArt)) and secondaryArt like '30%'
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bfea5acfa3868adcaeca1b7404b83280)

For Oracle 11g Release2 and Above:

```
with cte(MainArt,secondaryArt) as(

SELECT MainArt, secondaryArt 
            FROM MyData 
        WHERE TRIM(MainArt) = 'ACL-3382040385-4'
union all
select 
MyData.MainArt, MyData.secondaryArt
from MyData inner join cte on cte.secondaryArt=MyData.mainArt
        )
select * from cte where secondaryArt  like '30%'
```

Comment: I am using SQL. Could you help me transforming it into SQL? Also yes, it could be more than 2 levels so I think your code would be very helpful

Comment: It is in SQL only

Comment: Oracle SQL I am using

Comment: @BorislavStefanov You have added MySql Tag in your question but you are expecting the answer for Oracle.

Comment: @BorislavStefanov: looking at the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements in your question, you can't be using Oracle - that looks very much like MySQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I used creation as template. But in the end it is oracle SQL server where I can execute queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a self LEFT join:

```
SELECT COALESCE(m2.MainArt, m1.MainArt) MainArt,
       COALESCE(m2.secondaryArt, m1.secondaryArt) secondaryArt
FROM MyData m1 LEFT JOIN MyData m2
ON (m1.secondaryArt NOT LIKE '30%') AND (m2.MainArt = m1.secondaryArt)
WHERE TRIM(m1.MainArt) = 'ACL-3382040385-4'
ORDER BY COALESCE(m2.MainArt, m1.MainArt)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bfeb335406e9e503a3f551ab0d54e959).
Results:

```
> MainArt             | secondaryArt
> :------------------ | :-----------
> ACL-3382040385-4    | 30201039    
> ACL-4812070395-4 M1 | 30102024    
> ACL-4812070395-4 M2 | 30170054    
> ACL-4812070395-4 M3 | 30102024
```

Comment: it works but only if you have 2 levels. Many of my data has many levels and need deep drilldown. Anyway it is nice solution if you have only 2 levels

Comment: @BorislavStefanov this is the1st time that you use the word "level". I can't find it in your question.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. There can be many levels of items not starting with '30%' until you get all